# Standard meta data format for video like id3 tag for audio?

Tags: video, standards, metadata

Is there a standard meta data format for videos?

Are there other meta data formats generic enough to apply to a video file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there are no "bolted-on" metadata formats for videos (ID3 is a bolted-on metadata block for MP3s). Most of the video containers (AVI, OGG, MKV, MP4) have their own metadata formats.